# Merge 2 documents during aggregation and multiply

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, multiplication

i have the following records:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5a377b895a2840568b1034d5"),
   "reportId" : 1234,
   "quantity" : 346
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a377b935a2840568b1034d6"),
  "reportId" : 1234,
  "users" : 96
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a377ba35a2840568b1034d7"),
  "reportId" : 2345,
  "quantity" : 566    
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a377bac5a2840568b1034d8"),
  "reportId" : 2345,
  "users" : 66
}
```

I want the final output to be this way:

```
{'reportId': 1234, 'total':quantity * users}
```

In other words, I want the total to be the multiplication of users and quantity

I tried the following:

```
db.test1.aggregate([ 
{'$group':
  { '_id':'$reportId', 
    'total':{'$multiply':['$users','$quantity']}
  }
}])
```

This gave the the following error:

```
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The $multiply accumulator is a unary operator",
    "code" : 40237,
    "codeName" : "Location40237"
} : aggregate failed
```

So next i tried this:

```
db.test1.aggregate([ {
'$group':
         { '_id':'$reportId', 
           'document':{'$push':{'reportId':'$reportId', 
                       'quantity':'$quantity','users':'$users'}}}},
{'$unwind':'$document'}])
```

This gave me:

```
{ "_id" : 2345, "document" : { "reportId" : 2345, "quantity" : 566 } }
{ "_id" : 2345, "document" : { "reportId" : 2345, "users" : 66 } }
{ "_id" : 1234, "document" : { "reportId" : 1234, "quantity" : 346 } }
{ "_id" : 1234, "document" : { "reportId" : 1234, "users" : 96 } }
```

**My aim was to merge two records and apply multiplication.**

Is it possible to do so in mongoDB aggregation instead of getting an intermediate answer and looping through the partial result and getting the job done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you almost got it correct. I made this solution to combine the values from the two fields:

```
db.test1.aggregate([
    {"$group":{
        "_id":"$reportId",
        "qtd":{$sum:"$quantity"},
        "usrs":{$sum:"$users"}
    }},
    {"$project":{
        "_id":0,
        "reportId":"$_id",
        "total":
            {$multiply:["$qtd","$usrs"]}
    }}
])
```

Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: Yes the earlier solution had $push in it causing the error. This works :)

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept/upvote my anwer please.

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it, `$group` is a good way to do this. Something like this should work.

```
db.test1.aggregate([
    {"$group":
        {
            "_id": "$reportId",
            "usr": {"$sum": "$users"},
            "qty": {"$sum": "$quantity"}
        }
    },
    {"$project":
         {
             "_id": 0,
             "reportId": "$_id",
             "total": {"$multiply": ["$usr", "$qty"]}
         }}
])
```

Firstly we combine all `users` and `quantity` and then multiply them. During the `group` stage you need to accumulate the desired metrics.

Comment: error message:
"errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$push'",
"code" : 168,
"codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"

Comment: @israel.zinc umm, check the timestamp.

Comment: Yup works. Removing $push makes it work. Thank you :)

Comment: Well...it doesn't matter. We both can solve the problem. I will upvote your answer because it's also correct.

Comment: Guys have upvoted both ur answers... as long as it solves the issue no problem.Thank you for ur time :)

Comment: Good luck @Adarsh